# Edit value is not updated in Spring CRUD example

Tags: java, mysql, spring

Here is my code.When I check checkbox and click the edit button the value is fetched correctly.But edited value is not updated in mysql database as well as table.I'm using jdbc template for this example."location" field is select option value.

controller get the checkbox value and fetch data from database.after that the updated value is not shown in the table.

### HomeController.java

```
@RequestMapping("/edit")
public String update(Model model,@RequestParam Map<String,String> req){
    updateValue = new Integer(req.get("checkId"));
    List<Users> users = userdao.getUpdateRecord(updateValue);
    model.addAttribute("result",users);
    return "formedit";
}
@RequestMapping("/saveUpdate")
public String saveUpdate(Model model,@RequestParam Map<String,String> req){
    String name,storage,location,address;
    name = req.get("name");
    storage=req.get("storage");
    location=req.get("location");
    address = req.get("address");
    int row = userdao.updateRecord(updateValue,name,storage,location,address);
    String message = row+ "updated";
    model.addAttribute("message", message);
    result(model);
    return "home";
}
```

UsersDAO doesn't get the update value from formedit page.

### UsersDAO.java

```
public List<Users> getUpdateRecord(int updateValue){
    System.out.println("update value"+updateValue);
    String sql="select id,name,storage,location,address from customer where id="+updateValue;
    return jdbc.query(sql,new UsersMapper());
}

public int updateRecord(int id,String name,String storage,String location,String address){
    return jdbc.update("update customer set name = ?,storage = ?,location = ?,address=? where id = ?",id,name,storage,location,address);
```

### formedit.jsp

```
<form role="form" action="saveUpdate" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
  <c:forEach var="row" items="${result}">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-xs-4 text">Customer Name</label>
  <div class="col-xs-8">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value=${row.name }>
  </div>
  </div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-xs-4 text">Storage Location*</label>
<div class="col-xs-8">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="storage" value=${row.storage }>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-xs-4 text">Location</label>
<div class="col-xs-8">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="location" value=${row.location }>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-xs-4 text">Customer Address</label>
<div class="col-xs-8">
<textarea class="form-control" name="address">${row.address }</textarea>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-md col-md-offset-6" value="Update">
</div>
</c:forEach>
</form>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this is wrong:

```
 return jdbc.update("update customer set name = ?,storage = ?,location = ?,address=? where id = ?",id,name,storage,location,address);
```

The parameters order is incorrect, it doesnt find id with value address.

Comment: You can add them into a list and then convert the list into an array

Comment: yeah I got the answer